# Turn off Knife cut "auto complete" setting?

Tags: knife-tool

Everytime i use the knife tool, it wants to auto complete and i just want to make one line, non of the short cuts get rid of it either.

[image]

Comment: What is "to make one line" in this context? Resulting cut might depend on topology when Blender will automatically create supporting geometry holding that added one. If you mean you want to finish cutting at the green Knife tool dot to the right from the transform manipulator then where you expected supporting edge will go?

Answer (score -1):

Pressing Esc or RMB at any time cancels the tool, and pressing LMB or Enter confirms the cut, with the following options:

Enter will leave selected every edge except the new edges created from the cut.